# Xcode 6.3.2 crashing with error log : Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

Tags: xcode

Spent my whole day but could not resolve this issue.

My Xcode 6.3.2 is crashing after running project, I can clean , build but not able to run the project,

Getting following crash log.

(Xcode quit unexpectedly)

```
Process:               Xcode [775]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 6.3.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [775]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-29 14:54:02.345 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A238x)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        E1F011DD-CE9A-4933-5C84-A44288F55EB4


Time Awake Since Boot: 490 seconds

Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher Life Cycle Lock

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010

VM Regions Near 0x10:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010b28e000-000000010b28f000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode 6.3.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85f435ae mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85f4275f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85356d64 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85356255 __CFRunLoopRun + 1381
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85355aa8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8e00bb3f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
.
.
.
.

0x7fff8d459000 -     0x7fff8d564fff  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 433.1) <A3C4AEA5-230B-32C8-B0A1-6ACAF268DB3D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff8d565000 -     0x7fff8d5a0fff  com.apple.QD (3.48 - 300) <CE8F2627-BEAC-392D-9119-F74A89057015> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff8d5a1000 -     0x7fff8d5a4ff7  libdyld.dylib (352.2) <58EDCF19-9F5E-3EBB-9F2F-6AAF4F29C3A7> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8d5a5000 -     0x7fff8d5d5fff  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <F11BE6C8-861D-3C4C-BDD2-C803020608D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff8d5d6000 -     0x7fff8d5e7ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <68DE8C8A-0320-3269-AABF-D26D73F50001> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8d5e8000 -     0x7fff8d5ebfff  com.apple.LoginUICore (3.0 - 3.0) <3532BF6F-DEDC-3B96-818A-7BDA31371F29> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/LoginUICore
    0x7fff8d5ec000 -     0x7fff8d5edfff  libffi.dylib (18.1) <BE2846BF-C1BA-3136-903F-A914CDBC7328> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
    0x7fff8d616000 -     0x7fff8d61afff  com.apple.CommonPanels (1.2.6 - 96) <E6D92000-3031-3196-A48A-703FD3A3A8F4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff8d61b000 -     0x7fff8db17ffb  com.apple.JavaScriptCore (10538 - 10538.34.45) <E4CE5968-BF9E-3A38-817F-06F9F45BC5A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/JavaScriptCore
    0x7fff8db18000 -     0x7fff8db1cfff  libspindump.dylib (175) <127849C5-F478-3498-A61A-BB35C7EFDF3D> /usr/lib/libspindump.dylib
    0x7fff8db81000 -     0x7fff8db89fff  libMatch.1.dylib (20) <475874C9-420D-3FAE-AFC1-2BC203029C57> /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib
    0x7fff8db8c000 -     0x7fff8db94ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1205 - 1205) <4E75B741-4A42-3661-8FF6-8486E46C247F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff8db95000 -     0x7fff8dbd6fff  libGLU.dylib (10.0.37) <B24B929B-F25A-3EF3-9DB3-924C5DCB3C35> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff8dbf6000 -     0x7fff8dc24ff7  com.apple.CoreServicesInternal (213 - 213) <76B56330-535C-3A7F-93C3-5406C90F4B65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesInternal
    0x7fff8dc84000 -     0x7fff8dccaff7  libFontRegistry.dylib (131) <5FCBB586-43D9-3BDF-B7A1-F76463F1E043> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff8dddb000 -     0x7fff8dddffff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (79) <99239FC9-2952-30F5-8815-1D5C8665437D> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff8dde0000 -     0x7fff8dde1fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1212) <9461AF62-9273-3236-B9E6-FBAC96467BBC> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8dde2000 -     0x7fff8de17ff3  com.apple.datadetectors (5.0 - 266) <BBDE5727-A1F0-3FF5-A3DD-CCC843BD5E19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectors.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectors
    0x7fff8de18000 -     0x7fff8de1afff  com.apple.EFILogin (2.0 - 2) <F01E47FE-AD0F-3239-B9E5-149C710D98B0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/EFILogin
    0x7fff8de1b000 -     0x7fff8de1ffff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <0ED98CA0-4967-3B67-8790-B9A585CD2768> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff8de20000 -     0x7fff8de28ff7  com.apple.icloud.FindMyDevice (1.0 - 1) <7B006085-6F98-32A1-8668-E49D1453F03A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FindMyDevice.framework/Versions/A/FindMyDevice
    0x7fff8de29000 -     0x7fff8de4eff7  libJPEG.dylib (1220) <47442E97-3300-3D90-BF55-59ADDA9908DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff8de4f000 -     0x7fff8de53ff7  libGIF.dylib (1220) <A8E9FAD8-9F2D-3BA2-A90A-D3A5E305D01B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff8de54000 -     0x7fff8de69ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (260) <3398113B-8429-3D3E-B728-E44205BAD4E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8de6a000 -     0x7fff8de7bfff  libsystem_coretls.dylib (29) <B95FEAC8-6C16-382A-BE5C-5B34F6A4E8FD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff8df31000 -     0x7fff8df7dff7  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore (6.0 - 6.0) <4738AF4A-50A7-35B0-8234-0E9AFDDA1FA1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
    0x7fff8dfdc000 -     0x7fff8e2d8ffb  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 735) <B8553070-2225-33FE-AE52-3345740DED7E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff8e2d9000 -     0x7fff8e328ff7  libstdc++.6.dylib (104.1) <4081D505-933C-3ACA-9A8A-4C64DD48987E> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8e3a8000 -     0x7fff8e407ff7  com.apple.AE (677 - 677) <B2433B40-EE53-3F30-BAA3-3331BCFB7A10> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8e408000 -     0x7fff8e41afff  com.apple.CoreDuetDaemonProtocol (1.0 - 1) <73896274-B7CB-35A0-98DA-6384F493298D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol.framework/Versions/A/CoreDuetDaemonProtocol
    0x7fff8e41b000 -     0x7fff8e425ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.0 - 5.0) <D2F8B92A-B85D-3B0D-B24B-E74161DCB3A5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8e459000 -     0x7fff8e480ff7  com.apple.Sharing (258.2 - 258.2) <D362A74B-D5C9-3E59-9497-5B57C1966525> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Versions/A/Sharing
    0x7fff8e486000 -     0x7fff8e578ff7  libFontParser.dylib (123) <A264874E-22C8-321D-88B8-250F00926346> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff8e640000 -     0x7fff8e647fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <99760082-2292-3C65-960D-6B9B44E1B49E> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff8e64c000 -     0x7fff8e651ff3  libheimdal-asn1.dylib (386) <DB47F33B-5131-3890-937E-95E47F88DEBE> /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
    0x7fff8e652000 -     0x7fff8e654ffb  libCGXType.A.dylib (722.7) <A4E89A53-B491-363A-8C20-FADFE7BF2738> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
    0x7fff8e68c000 -     0x7fff8e691fff  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (112) <4C3B20D2-18FB-35BE-A695-8E56BAC1D3A8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff8e692000 -     0x7fff8e692ff7  liblaunch.dylib (496.0.0.0.4) <25D0EE80-85D2-379D-BF76-09B417C0FD19> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8e693000 -     0x7fff8e820fff  libBLAS.dylib (1119) <93F54197-FEA7-31A1-B960-CCD78F87702E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff8e821000 -     0x7fff8e913fff  libxml2.2.dylib (26) <9D71C417-581E-3CD6-ABA1-7111101A687D> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff8e914000 -     0x7fff8e98cff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1039.0.0.0.2) <B540F378-33CA-3ACA-B70B-7C8F2737690A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff8e98d000 -     0x7fff8e995fff  libsystem_platform.dylib (61) <90DD0380-D3ED-346A-B4A8-1F1D11D42032> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8e996000 -     0x7fff8e9f6fff  com.apple.ISSupport (1.9.9 - 57) <4ED16306-30E5-3A6C-AFA2-7DAF06E4F6DD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ISSupport.framework/Versions/A/ISSupport
    0x7fff8e9f7000 -     0x7fff8ea0dff7  com.apple.CoreMediaAuthoring (2.2 - 950) <CA45FE03-8A24-3B68-BD91-C99855F33966> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaAuthoring.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaAuthoring
    0x7fff8ea0e000 -     0x7fff8ea17fff  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <B90A7896-8822-36C6-8C52-E2FC73CBAB4C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
    0x7fff8ea18000 -     0x7fff8ee25ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1119) <6AAD6821-F578-382A-952A-BF47B13BE997> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8ee26000 -     0x7fff8ee28fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (10.0.37) <5F4B59D4-14AE-321E-8692-0E277FDB2C3B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff8f0be000 -     0x7fff8f0effff  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.3 - 1.3) <03140600-6273-309A-A9C8-8F1B1FA504E2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
    0x7fff8f306000 -     0x7fff8f38cffb  com.apple.CoreUtils (1.0 - 100.11) <F815B06B-01BC-3A47-8CFD-D679C39E5A3F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/Versions/A/CoreUtils
    0x7fff8f38d000 -     0x7fff8f38dfff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (160) <4D6CE841-6EE0-3A0D-98CE-74E1924F8EDB> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff8f3a1000 -     0x7fff8f3eeff3  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (10.0 - 448) <BC611858-48F5-3E4E-ADEE-392BC63BB762> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff8f3ef000 -     0x7fff8f3fafff  com.apple.AppSandbox (4.0 - 229.0.0.0.2) <B3A92BD1-9AB4-3432-B7F5-2846369CE6B7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSandbox.framework/Versions/A/AppSandbox
    0x7fff8f43a000 -     0x7fff8fcc2ffb  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 722.7) <D7C241DC-76EF-3FE2-B99B-4887C500A632> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8fcc3000 -     0x7fff8fd1eff7  libTIFF.dylib (1220) <C34DF536-AC35-3C76-8408-FF3790B9582B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff8fd1f000 -     0x7fff8fd38ff7  com.apple.AppleVPAFramework (1.0.19 - 1.0.19) <0CE02E66-34EC-3A2D-B35F-E8DC66366544> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA
    0x7fff8fd39000 -     0x7fff8fd3dfff  libcache.dylib (69) <69FA8935-1BDF-369C-8DA5-37F2E651FC1D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8fd3e000 -     0x7fff8fd40fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (671) <EE252873-1698-31F7-9431-1CD4C954DA39> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8fd41000 -     0x7fff8fd6dfff  libsandbox.1.dylib (344) <CB592652-5354-338A-9A68-6030F834B1A6> /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib
    0x7fff8fd86000 -     0x7fff8fd99ff7  libextension.dylib (19.1) <A390B34E-1D40-3100-ABAB-C7C4BFDBA0BE> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x7fff8fdc6000 -     0x7fff8fdccfff  libsystem_trace.dylib (47.0.0.0.2) <3496EA08-6D61-37F0-A557-8AD734F0480E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff8fdcf000 -     0x7fff90036fff  com.apple.imageKit (2.6 - 822) <B60B7CB2-2343-3B58-857B-603900397ED3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/ImageKit
    0x7fff90037000 -     0x7fff9003afff  com.apple.AppleSystemInfo (3.0 - 3.0) <9DBB4765-F1E7-381F-820E-1A5599F127E8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSystemInfo.framework/Versions/A/AppleSystemInfo
    0x7fff9003b000 -     0x7fff90048ff3  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 221.1) <4F30E9C5-B65D-3309-A2A2-59A7BE50381C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
    0x7fff90049000 -     0x7fff900dfff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0) <6579D014-B4FA-3AD4-A428-CDAC034DFCA9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff90452000 -     0x7fff90460fff  com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsFoundation (8.0 - 1449.5) <DA771056-488B-33BE-9AFF-2EA3106366C2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContactsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ContactsFoundation
    0x7fff90461000 -     0x7fff90476fff  com.apple.AppContainer (4.0 - 229.0.0.0.2) <607484EA-7E90-383A-907B-A1A71D6AD284> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppContainer.framework/Versions/A/AppContainer
    0x7fff90477000 -     0x7fff904c4fff  com.apple.AppleVAFramework (5.0.31 - 5.0.31) <E10092AD-B101-33EE-8D77-31008BE19F96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVA
    0x7fff904c5000 -     0x7fff9054efff  com.apple.CoreSymbolication (3.1 - 56067) <4A8A6D8F-EB11-358E-8215-31EAE5005E5E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
    0x7fff90558000 -     0x7fff9055dfff  com.apple.MediaAccessibility (1.0 - 59) <80F47DED-75CE-3782-BA09-2937B94C1D46> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/Versions/A/MediaAccessibility
    0x7fff9055e000 -     0x7fff9055fff7  com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsData (8.0 - 1449.5) <FB7C6360-BAA8-342B-90D7-AECBF86A750B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContactsData.framework/Versions/A/ContactsData
    0x7fff90560000 -     0x7fff905d2ff3  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (360 - 368) <C2420B57-20E3-3439-8F17-24D476CCFA9A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff905d3000 -     0x7fff90613ff7  libGLImage.dylib (10.0.37) <F82C0AD6-856D-33CC-8AF3-03FFE3F070AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff90614000 -     0x7fff906a4ff7  libCoreStorage.dylib (433) <04176B01-8C8C-3398-AFD5-BF288B033BC8> /usr/lib/libCoreStorage.dylib
    0x7fff906a5000 -     0x7fff907deff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1038) <06AB60C9-BD72-3D79-BBB8-8A668A6F7672> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff907df000 -     0x7fff90a5aff3  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (5.05 - 745) <FDDEA5CD-CC52-3628-AE2D-5BEFD408B09B> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff90a5b000 -     0x7fff90c3affb  libicucore.A.dylib (531.17) <4CD56103-046A-360B-A5BC-B81A103BBDBC> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff90c3b000 -     0x7fff90c78ff3  com.apple.bom (14.0 - 193.4) <1B56DECF-1268-3EB2-9947-FFFDA339325C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
    0x7fff90c79000 -     0x7fff90e6afff  com.apple.CFNetwork (696.0.2 - 696.0.2) <FE250843-2589-3DE5-B869-4C6173EB0D80> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff90e6b000 -     0x7fff90ef9ff7  com.apple.CorePDF (4.0 - 4) <F2E8B74C-B7DE-3240-A72E-2D2EE5EA0520> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF
    0x7fff90fab000 -     0x7fff90fb9ff7  com.apple.opengl (10.0.37 - 10.0.37) <2971E4B4-B532-34C3-8E27-44A24712F193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff90fba000 -     0x7fff90fc3fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (96) <B5C91A1D-6806-32C3-80DA-5E09F1418E59> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff90fc4000 -     0x7fff90ff5fff  libtidy.A.dylib (15.15) <95050F6F-BF43-3BA7-BF19-B5098EF37D23> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
    0x7fff90ff6000 -     0x7fff91b37fff  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1318.14) <0A841BED-69BD-3286-8174-DE4015885B0A> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff91b48000 -     0x7fff91bb2fff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (5.0 - 500.22) <2645534D-F82D-385E-8321-18226D1A84BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fff91bfe000 -     0x7fff91c6cfff  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <BA4C3844-7E5C-3BC4-9230-8D8C3838DA6B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff91cac000 -     0x7fff91cadfff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <8E7791AA-D243-3928-8684-B3FDC090D51C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff91cae000 -     0x7fff91d24fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14) <E66F8A95-E4E3-382C-92F1-06E6ADF4957C> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff91d25000 -     0x7fff91d71ff7  libcups.2.dylib (397) <1E25463A-896F-331B-890A-73CE413C02C1> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff91d80000 -     0x7fff91da4ff7  com.apple.quartzfilters (1.8.0 - 1.7.0) <2C90E3A2-63E8-3E91-8B93-702DCC2AD67F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzFilters.framework/Versions/A/QuartzFilters
    0x7fff91da5000 -     0x7fff921d4ffb  com.apple.vision.FaceCore (3.1.5 - 3.1.5) <B57D146D-3449-30A3-A630-B422C57772F6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/FaceCore
    0x7fff921ed000 -     0x7fff92705ff7  com.apple.MediaToolbox (1.0 - 1491.1) <D2D970C6-84EB-3352-BE35-CFF4300FB6B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/Versions/A/MediaToolbox
    0x7fff92706000 -     0x7fff92708ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (344) <69ACEB2A-8DC9-3B89-8ECF-667AD6B485FC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff92709000 -     0x7fff936caffb  com.apple.WebCore (10538 - 10538.34.46) <D6967990-1C16-3B2C-95A1-7C80E59EA68A> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
    0x7fff936cb000 -     0x7fff936d4fff  libGFXShared.dylib (10.0.37) <A06944A2-FF25-3635-936C-A0D731646661> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff936d5000 -     0x7fff936ffff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 219) <2FDA269C-B03D-3FAC-8B80-8364F01E46C0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff93700000 -     0x7fff93749fff  com.apple.DiskManagement (7.0 - 828) <5A7D246C-2F31-35BE-8C43-15C811935C45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/A/DiskManagement
    0x7fff93767000 -     0x7fff93793ff7  com.apple.framework.SystemAdministration (1.0 - 1.0) <14E020DA-EECE-3130-87D9-2AFD5DD48FB8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Versions/A/SystemAdministration
    0x7fff937bf000 -     0x7fff937c1fff  com.apple.marco (10.0 - 1000) <F420750C-1603-3CB7-AFA9-526D8819C04A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Versions/A/Marco
    0x7fff937df000 -     0x7fff93b08ff7  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1132.13) <0FCF00EA-8754-31DF-B0D4-097B01794800> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff93b09000 -     0x7fff93b09fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <3C92E5EE-E004-357B-A7CA-D2DF0951AD44> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff93b22000 -     0x7fff93b85fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <DD0E2328-D156-380B-85E7-E6A3DC652E29> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff93b86000 -     0x7fff93b86fff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.12 - 1.12) <0DFB8DC6-294A-381B-8699-C1FFD7727389> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff93ba1000 -     0x7fff93bbfffb  libresolv.9.dylib (57) <155594B2-C556-3900-999F-58388DE66582> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff93c5d000 -     0x7fff93ce9fe7  libsystem_c.dylib (1041) <A34BCDEC-6C21-31C5-A233-BD36BD0A69D7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff93cea000 -     0x7fff93cecff7  libutil.dylib (38) <FD1C77F5-C8F8-3C95-AFE4-CA7B12BC9242> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
    0x7fff93ced000 -     0x7fff93ceeff7  libodfde.dylib (22) <9F340061-8B98-3330-B86A-307B02D81526> /usr/lib/libodfde.dylib
    0x7fff93cef000 -     0x7fff93deaff7  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 1) <EBB8B0C0-A659-3E03-AB2F-58D6CBB73341> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
    0x7fff93deb000 -     0x7fff93df8ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (36) <1CE70D65-3D62-3857-BFA0-1D14C5FE0BC2> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff94681000 -     0x7fff94684fff  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <A24F08FF-382E-3104-A437-EA9E5485F0AC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff946a7000 -     0x7fff946a7fff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <B57BE642-5B41-35D7-B5EE-9755F2D31C1E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff946a8000 -     0x7fff946acff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (160.0.0.0.1) <44D7BDF8-C833-3F3B-85B6-C76ACDB81BC4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff946ad000 -     0x7fff946b9ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.10 - 184) <07DD4378-48B9-39AE-AB22-6D326069965F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff946ba000 -     0x7fff946c0fff  com.apple.private.XprotectFrameWork.XprotectFramework (1.0 - 1) <52C1C43E-2895-33D4-8F69-C3BED8711392> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XprotectFramework.framework/Versions/A/XprotectFramework
    0x7fff946c1000 -     0x7fff946c3ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (6) <CE029CE6-341E-316D-A63E-36018A87B630> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff946c4000 -     0x7fff946f0ffb  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 135.0) <B28D991E-218C-3822-8EE8-565D6C218085> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff946f1000 -     0x7fff946f1fff  com.apple.Carbon (154 - 157) <CACCB2F7-02F3-3D2A-ABB9-A12E44EE9D1F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff946f2000 -     0x7fff946f7fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <19211A94-096B-32DC-B5FC-CD9496E682D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff946f8000 -     0x7fff946ffff7  libcopyfile.dylib (115) <802774AD-A71F-3A46-A7A9-810F8B8DA205> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff94700000 -     0x7fff94738fff  com.apple.RemoteViewServices (2.0 - 94) <4B2A84D0-9D26-3694-AD2C-916917B2BC19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteViewServices.framework/Versions/A/RemoteViewServices

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 9
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 17159
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=412.2M resident=389.2M(94%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=23.0M(6%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=62.4M(5%) resident=131.0M(11%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(89%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                    3804K
CG image                              680K
CG raster data                         60K
CG shared images                      332K
CoreAnimation                        6388K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                               8K
CoreUI image data                     112K
Dispatch continuations               8192K
Foundation                             16K
Image IO                               52K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              123.1M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         80K
OpenCL                                 16K
SQLite page cache                    1792K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                16.2M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16.8M
WebKit Malloc                         464K
__DATA                               44.7M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                          108.7M
__TEXT                              303.5M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                          59.3M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.7G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      757.1M


Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.2f41
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313630304B53482D3447202020202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x014F, 0x4A4D313630304B53482D3447202020202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.77.8.2)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0d49 14130, 3 services, 16 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: Does 6.3.1 work?  I've avoided 6.3.2 because of too many complaints of crashing and other errors.

Comment: I was using 6.0 earlier (was working fine) which has iOS 8.0 and for iOS 8.3 I updated xcode to 6.3.2
should i use 6.3.1 ?

Comment: Xcode 6.3.2 is not yet stable, I had to install 6.1 to solve my problem. 
I hope this information could save someone's day !

Comment: 6.3.1 seems ok too - you might want to try that.